# MS Project single resource assigned to multiple concurrent activities

Tags: ms-project

In Microsoft Project (MSP), is it possible to have two parallel/concurrent activities with the same resource assigned to both? For example:

[image: parallel tasks example]

The worker resource "matt" is assigned to both activities, hence the overallocation error showing in the info column (red human icon).

Why do I require such a structure you may ask? In reality, one task would continually be temporarily interrupted to do the other one, and vice versa. But in MSP, it would be counter-productive to do so. Hence, my simplified approach - parallel activities.

So how should I fix this issue?

- Ignore it?
- Allocate 50% of the resource to each (and fix up finish dates which are automatically extended by MSP?)
- Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

if they indeed overlap then the best way to put this in your project is to allocate 50% on each task.  But why fix up finish date, the program will recalculate the new duration of the task based on the new work, while the allocation is lowered to 50% then the duration should double ... Or you can declare the task as duration driven if that is the case, for such tasks duration will stay as set though allocation is changed

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a better solution. So solution number 2 that is adjusting assignment units is the best in your case.